# TeXstudio: Building and Compiling Issue

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio, and am running into some difficulties. I have MikTex (evidently this is needed), but it still won't compile. If I add any new content to my LateX document, and then click the green arrow button, it loads an old version of my document, but doesn't include the newly typed content.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: There are two green arrows. First use the left one (double arrow). Or better, press F6 to run `pdflatex`. Then F7 to view the `pdf`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Why don't you make this an answer, so that I might upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two green arrows. The left one (double arrow) is to build and view. The right one (single arrow) is to view the output.

Note that it will depend what is your default builder.

If you want to use an specific you can press the corresponding shortcut.

On `Tools > Commands` menu you can see them

[image]

as below:

[image]

You can set up the Build function here
[image]

Comment: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "note 1".tex this is error my tex studio showing. what can i do?