# TeXstudio suddenly won't compile!

Tags: texstudio

I put my work (which was working just fine) from my office computer into my Google drive folder. I then accessed this from home and added more text into the document. However, when I compile it, it doesn't acknowledge the new work I've added. If I try and edit what was previously compiling it doesn't recognise the changes but just compiles the old stuff. It's like it's 'stuck' on the old version. No error messages are thrown by TeXstudio.

This could be a problem with my home version of TeXstudio but I can't see anything obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Check if you are not using some Master Document.

Comment: Go to the [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) site, click on "Create a New Paper", paste your code into it and see if it compiles. If it does that would confirm your suspicion that something wrong with your home version of TeXstudio,

Comment: (1) Make sure there isn't a previous local copy that is being processed in place of the new file. (1a) Make sure there isn't an older copy of the `.pdf` that is getting opened in place of the new one. (2) Save your changes, open the newly saved file in a different text editor and see if your changes were preserved. (3) Delete auxiliary files and try compiling from the command line. (4) Try to find a way to provide more information....

Comment: I would first try `ctrl-N` to make a new file, enter a very short code example and press compile. See if it works, if it doesn't, save the file to a local folder of yours and try again. If it still doesn't work, you have a more serious problem - but I don't think so if TexStudio doesn't throw any errors. In case your old document is somehow messed up, you could always copy-paste everything into a new document and save it on your hard disk.

Comment: Try pushing the Build and View (double green arrow), not the Compile (single green arrow).  This was suggested by:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151948/texstudio-building-and-compiling-issue

Comment: It has often happened to me that google drive started syncing files (aux and index files) while working on a document, when google drive does this texstudio cannot write to the files, and that results in errors in compilation. Saving under a different name doesn't always help as google drive will sync the new files as well. The workaround is shutting down google drive, or pausing the sync and saving the files under a new name

Answer (score 5):

I also use a few different computers and the same thing happened to me. And the reason was, that I had forgotten to install a Tex distribution on one of the computers (TexStudio is just an editor, it won't compile anything if you haven't installed Tex.)

Solution: Install TeXLive or MikTeX and your TexStudio will start working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.